# Си: параметры командной строки

Tags: c, время, switch, командная-строка, case

Всем доброго времени суток. Задача не проходит по времени, подскажите что не так пожалуйста

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

int main()
{
    char c;
    FILE* input = fopen ("input.txt", "r");
    FILE* output = fopen ("output.txt", "w");
    do {
        
        fscanf(input,"%c", &c);
        switch (c) {
        case '"':
            fprintf(output,"[");
            fscanf(input,"%c", &c);
            while (c != '"') {
                fprintf(output,"%c", c);
                fscanf(input,"%c", &c);
            }
            fprintf(output,"]\n");
            break;
        case ' ':
            break;
        default:
            printf(output,"[");
            while (c != ' ' && c != '\n') {
                fprintf(output,"%c", c);
                fscanf(input,"%c", &c);
            }
            fprintf(output,"]\n");
        }
    
    } while (c != '\n');
    
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    
    return 0;
}
```

условие:
В этой задаче предлагается реализовать алгоритм выделения параметров из командной
строки в простом случае.
Командная строка будет содержать только следующие символы:
∙ латинские буквы (большие и маленькие) и цифры,
∙ пробел (ASCII 32),
∙ двойные кавычки (ASCII 34).
Параметры записываются в командную строку подряд в порядке следования. Между
каждыми двумя соседними параметрами вставляется один или несколько пробелов, чтобы
отделить их друг от друга. Параметр может быть целиком заключён в двойные кавычки.
Если внутри параметра есть пробелы, он заключён в двойные кавычки обязательно. Символов двойных кавычек в самих параметрах нет — ими лишь можно окружать параметры.
Все параметры непустые.
Командная строка, которую необходимо разобрать, записана в единственной строке входного файла. Её длина не превышает 100 символов. Учтите, что в этой командной строке
отсутствует имя исполняемого файла. В выходной файл нужно вывести искомые параметры
командной строки, по одному параметру в строке. Каждый параметр должен быть заключён в квадратные скобки. Особый нулевой параметр (саму командную строку) выводить не
нужно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите задачу

Comment: извиняюсь. теперь условия прикреплены

Comment: В задаче ничего не сказано про наличие символов переноса строки `'\n'` в input.txt, а достижение конца файла вы не проверяете, поэтому ваш цикл `while (c != '\n')` скорее всего является бесконечным, а бесконечность не будет проходить по времени

Comment: блин, точно! спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Без подробностей:

1. Нужно вводить строку не по одному символу, а сразу всю, с помощью *fgets()*
2. После ввода строки пробегаем по всем символам ( for(j=0; j<strlen(..), j++) ) и считаем двойные кавычки. Если получили нечётное количество - печатаем сообщение об ошибке и выходим.
3. Если количество кавычек > 0, то вырезаем из исходной строки куски от чётного символа кавычки до нечётного и помещаем вырезанный кусок в список параметров. Исходную строку сдвигаем влево, что бы не образовывалось разрывов в строке.
4. Пункт 3 повторяем, пока есть ещё закавыченные части.
5. Всё, что осталось, с помощью *strtoc()* (http://all-ht.ru/inf/prog/c/func/strtok.html) рразбиваем на параметры и запоминаем в таблице параметров.
6. Печатаем таблицу параметров.

Comment: `strtok()` не нужно использовать в новом коде. Есть нормальный `strsep()` для этого.